# ArcGIS API for JavaScript and dojo : lang.clone for selected features from a feature layer

Tags: dojo, clone, arcgis-js-api

I would like to clone in a new array (a deep copy without references) the features I have selected from a feature layer with the getSelectedFeatures() method.

I try to use lang.clone from dojo but it doesn't work. I have this error : "TypeError: this._url is null".

I understand it cames from the feature layer. But I don't know how to fix this error or even if it's possible to do what I want to do by this way. I'm quite new with JSAPI.

I already used lang.clone with serviceAreaPolygons from serviceAreaSolveResult and it worked very well !

Could someone help me on this problem ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you please post a code snippet that is causing the error in question? Thanks!

Comment: Thanks. I find another solution with ToJson. I convert the features to json and create a new graphic from that json.

Comment: Seems like you got the alternative answer for the question.. so i suggest either you post your answer here for other or vote to delete the question....

Comment: As said above, I use the ToJson method to convert features to json and push them into a new Graphic object `var graphic = centres.getSelectedFeatures()[i].toJson();
                   var selectionGraphic = new Graphic(graphic);
                   selection.push(selectionGraphic);`

Answer (score 0):

[By Clemini comments] As said above, using the `ToJson` method to convert features to json and push them into a new Graphic object

```
var graphic = centres.getSelectedFeatures()[i].toJson(); 
var selectionGraphic = new Graphic(graphic); 
selection.push(selectionGraphic);
```

***This will resolve above error.***

***Hoping this will help others too :)***